# Commit several projects in Eclipse SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, working-set

I am working on several projects in Eclipse. The projects are checked out from an SVN repository. The projects also depend on each other. Currently, if I want to commit them, I have to mark each project and then call **Team** `->` **Commit**.

Is it possible to commit everything without selecting particular projects? That's quite annoying. It is especially difficult to remember which projects were changed today and which were not. I tried doing this with working sets but I do not see any option of committing them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean [changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.changelists.html), not [working sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set)?

Answer (score 1):

You can only commit them together if they are all part of the same working copy. If you checked each project out individually via Eclipse, this will not be the case.

Unless there's *very* tight coupling between the projects, you normally should not be committing multiple projects at once. It's not about making things less convenient to you, but about making your commits smaller, self-contained "units".

Comment: OK, I understand. Is it possible to checkout complete working copy with Eclipse? The problem is that my two projects depend on each other and it often happens that I develop on both in parallel. And then I want to commit both at the same time for consistency reasons.